# Find point on a plane with given azimuth and radial distance

Tags: geometry, spherical-coordinates

Point $A$ shall be projected  on a plane with the height $k$ which is parallel to the xy axis.
The new point needs to have the same distance to the origin $ r $  and azimuth $ \theta $ on the xy plane. 
Searched for is the correct $\phi $.

[image]

I used the following formulas to convert the cartesian coordinates to it's spherical representation.

$$
Carthesian: (x,y,z) = A \\
Spherical: (r,\theta,\phi) 
$$

Spherical to Carthesian

$$
x = r * \sin(\phi) * \cos(\theta)\\
y = r * \sin(\phi) * \sin(\theta) \\
z = r * \cos(\phi)  \\
$$

Carthesian to Spherical

$$
r = \left\lvert \left\lvert A \right\rvert \right\rvert = \sqrt{ x^{ 2 } + y^{ 2 } + z^{ 2 } } \\
\theta = \arctan{\frac{ y }{ x }} \\
\phi = \arccos(\frac{ z }{ x }) \\
r = \textrm{radial distance}\\
\theta = \textrm{inclination (elevation)}\\
\phi = aziumuth
$$

I tried to solve several equations with the assumption that the magnitude and $ \theta $ of both vectors need to be the same, the y of point B is known (k) as well well as xyz of point A, but did not manage to solve these. 
My next best bet would be to create a linear equation and trying to find the intersection with the plane, but I haven't worked with spherical coordinates before and am a bit lost here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to determine $\phi_B$ seems to use the $Z$ coordinates. For the plane $z=k$, while for point B $z=r\cos(\phi_B)$, so:
$$k=r\cos(\phi_B) \rightarrow \phi_B=\arccos(k/r)$$
(where $r=r_A=r_B$ is known).
While also $\theta=\theta_A=\theta_B$ is given.

So if you need the coordinates in "XYZ", u can simply use the conversion rules you wrote up.